# Migrate data using Ssis pacakage

Tags: ssis, schema, foreign-key-relationship

I am new to ssis world, I need to migrate my client's old data to our new database, the problem is schema is completely differ and in some cases i need to save data in two or more different tables and arrange foreign key relationship between them.
Any help is much appriciated

Comment: What are you specifically asking for help with?

Comment: Break the project into small tasks and tackle each one at a time.

Comment: Any example link or Idea will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a staging database basically a 'bridge', you will make the database as close to the new database as possible, yet still with the old database in mind, you send the old database data to the staging database using SSIS and from there if you wish you can clean the data without interrupting business processes and validate the data to make sure it is balancing to the previous database data count.

From there you move it straight into the new database again with SSIS there should be no issues if the staging database was set up correctly